# Powershell: start and stop flask server

Tags: windows, powershell, flask, kill-process

I wrote a powershell script to start my flask server, run my tests then stop my server.  It starts the server and runs my tests. However, when it kills the $server process, it leaves the actual server process running and I can see the window for this process still open. How can I kill the server after the tests finish running?

```perl
$db_id = [guid]::NewGuid().ToString()
$env:AUTHZ_DB_FILE = 'Authorization ' + $db_id
$server = Start-Process py -ArgumentList '-m', 'authz.test.server' -PassThru 

Write-Output $server.Id

py -m authz.test.tests $args

Stop-Process -Id $server.Id
```

Comment: your code appears to be starting python ... is the _original python process_ still running OR is the process you see one that was started by the 1st python script?

Answer (score 1):

Try

Stop-Process -Id $server.Id -Force